# Combine nginx proxy_pass definitions

Tags: nginx, proxy

In an nginx configuration, how would one combine two `proxy_pass` definitions into one location block, so that the first slash is not proxied to the server when not specifying a trailing slash?

I currently have

```
server {

  ...

  location /mylocation {
    proxy_pass http://myproxy:1234/;
  }
  location /mylocation/ {
    proxy_pass http://myproxy:1234/;
  }

}
```

Is there any way to combine both location definitions into one location block?

Comment: Are you still looking into this? You should be able to solve it with regular expressions.